# How to alter an EVENT in mysql and change what is run

Tags: php, mysql

My DBA set up many events that run SQL code thousands of lines long. Now that he is gone how do I change the EVENT DO statement when the code that is run is 1000s of lines?

I have tried doing it in workbench, it just runs the 1000s of lines of code
I have tied PHP PDO to run an ALTER EVENT 'name'
                DO :placeholder
I have tried mysqli

all with standard bind errors.  I have been able to insert the code into a text field in another table so I do know the php PDO works and was thinking is there a SQL comand to copy this feild into the event?

Comment: please show us the code, but i don't think that you can use parameters in events

Comment: As the code, I am trying to change is 1000s of lines and has business-critical data I can't post it but the sudo code is:

   $query =  "ALTER EVENT event_name

                DO 
                    $event "; 
    if ( ! $mysqli->query( $query ) ) {
            echo "<h1>Execute failed: (" . $mysqli->error . ") </h1>" . $stmt->error;

    }
the error message is Execute failed: (No database selected)

Comment: php would replace the name that is ok so, placeholder and prepared statements don#t work there, if the user can enter event name, you have to check it and remove everthing other than text.

Comment: does the name of the event not allow spaces or characters like | and/or ` (ticket mark) around the name?
code:
ALTER EVENT databasename.`name of | event proceess`  note ticket and spaces

Comment: i never tried i folow the good pracvtise rules for naming. but you could write "ALTER EVENT databsename.`$myevent`  DO spaces without backticks(Which you can't see here in the comments) but they are around $myevent) are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can do between the backticks very much, but it is not recomended

```
$sql = "ALTER EVENT myschema.`my | event`
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.mytable SET mycol = mycol + 1;";
```

ALTER EVETNS isn't supported by Prepared statements with parmeters, you can only use strung replacement. but there you must you backticks for columns and apostrophes for strings

```
$sql = "ALTER EVENT myschema.`$myeventt`
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL $mytime HOUR
    DO
      UPDATE myschema.`$mytable` SET `$mycol` = `$mycol` + $myaddnumber,`$mycol2` = '$mystrimng';";
```

this you can use with pdo or mysqli
And php would repace the variables

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found that works is:

DROP EVENT IF EXISTS databasename.`processes_name`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS databasename.`processes_name`;

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2018-02-05 08:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE

DO BEGIN

***thousands of lines of SQL code ***

END; $$;

that is it
I was missing the BEGIN and END part